# How do you read the .prof files generated by web2py's profiler?

Tags: profiling, web2py

If I [run web2py with the -F option](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1972/profiling-in-web2py), it will generate a .prof file. How do I read the contents of this file? [Hotshot](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hotshot.html) doesn't appear to work (I tried RunSnakeRun as well).

Comment: I have not used the web2py -F option. I tried the profiling option mentioned in this link, and it seemed to work: http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web2py uses cProfile; I found something that will load the cProfile generated file and spit out output to a webpage:

http://ymichael.com/2014/03/08/profiling-python-with-cprofile.html

`pip install cprofilev`, then run cprofilev on the .prof file. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

`snakeviz` is a module/binary to view and generate cprofile .prof files. Recommended by *the* search engine. I really like its Sunburst plot.

https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/